# How can I define that all values belong to another one and meet requirement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and now I want to define which mentor has all his interns with marks "5".

I tried to add this:

```
SELECT Mentor_lname FROM Table WHERE Mentor_lname = ALL (SELECT Mentor_lname
FROM Table WHERE mark = 5));
```

But it doesn't help, I have already spent a few hours to get a proper result. Maybe I use "ALL" incorrectly?

[Table]

[image: 1]

The expected result is `Natarov`.

Comment: If you want to get the intern names, why are you using `SELECT Mentor_lname`? Shouldn't that be `SELECT Intern_lname`?

Comment: Do you mean the mentors where all their marks were 5?

Comment: What is `Practice_result`? Is that the same as `Table` or another table?

Comment: I mean some mentors have all their interns with mark "5", so I want to find them

Comment: Can you add the expected result?

Comment: Column with the last names of mentors that have all their interns with mark "5" is shown

Comment: That's what you just said. Can you show the actual rows you want, to make it clear?

Comment: The question says "I want to define all interns". But now you say you want the mentor names. Please edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: In this case it is only mentor "Natarov" which matches this criteria

Comment: Why won't you edit the question like I ask?

Comment: In question it is said "all interns of which MENTOR"

Comment: That sounds to me like you want to return the interns whose mentors meet the criteria, not the mentors.

Comment: If you just want to return the mentors, the intern names are irrelevant.

Comment: OK, I edited question to make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `5` is the maximum possible mark, you can just check whether `MIN(mark) == 5` for each mentor.

```
SELECT Mentor_lname
FROM Table
GROUP BY Mentor_lname
HAVING MIN(mark) == 5
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you want to do this :

```
select * 
from tablename
where Mentor_lname IN (
   SELECT Mentor_lname
   FROM tablename2 
   WHERE Practise_result.mark = 5
    );
```

but if only 1 table is involved then :

```
select * from tablename where mark = 5
```